# Facing problem in shaking row if it is clicked second time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Explanation -:

1. there are 4 rows each row has it's uid  ,
2. suppose user select a row , shake variable in ts file  holds uid of that row
3. User can select only one at a time
4. when user try to select another row , that row shakes

> Problem is -: After selecting one row - : 
>    - user try to select another row it shakes 
>    - but when user clicks on that row 2nd time again it dosen't shake

Html

```
 <ion-row align-items-center [class.shake]="shake==playerValue.playerUid ? 'shake' : null">
                <ion-col col-3>
                  <!-- <div class="create-team-imge" >
                      <img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}>
                    </div> -->
                  <div class="create-team-imge">
                    <ion-avatar item-star no-line>
                      <button (click)="playerinfo(i)"><img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></button>
                    </ion-avatar>
                    <ion-badge>
                      <ion-icon name="information"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-badge>
                  </div>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-md-9 col-9 (click)="setClickedRow(i)">
                  <ion-row align-items-center>
                    <ion-col col-md-8 col-7>

                      <p>{{playerValue.playerName}}</p>
                      <p>Selected By {{playerValue.selectedBy}}</p>
                      <p class="country" >{{playerValue.teamName}}</p>
                      <p class="points"> Points:
                        <span>{{playerValue.totalPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-md-4 col-5 class="cradit">
                      <p>
                        <span>{{playerValue.playerCreditPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                      <button ion-button icon-only>
                        <ion-icon [name]="playerValue.isSelected? 'close' : 'ios-checkmark'"></ion-icon>
                      </button>
                    </ion-col>
                  </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
```

css

```
 @keyframes shake {
      0% {transform: translateX(0);}
      12.5% {transform: translateX(-56px) rotateY(-5deg)}
      37.5% {transform: translateX(55px) rotateY(4deg)}
      62.5% {transform: translateX(-33px) rotateY(-2deg)}
      87.5% {transform: translateX(22px) rotateY(1deg)}
      100% {transform: translateX(0)}
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes shake {
      0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
      12.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-56px) rotateY(-5deg)}
      37.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(55px) rotateY(4deg)}
      62.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-33px) rotateY(-2deg)}
      87.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(22px) rotateY(1deg)}
      100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0)}
      }

      .shake {
      -webkit-animation: shake 600ms ease-in-out;
      animation: shake 600ms ease-in-out;
      }
```

ts -:

```
export class CreateteamPage {
 shake: any = 0;

 playerSelection(playerType, index) {
    console.log('total player ' + this.totalPlayer);
    console.log('index  ' + this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].maxSelection);
    if (this.totalCreaditPoint < parseFloat(this.players[index].playerCreditPoint)) {

      if (this.totalPlayer >= 11) {
        this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'u can select only 11 players',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top',
        });
        toast.present();
      } else {
        this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'u dont have enough credit point',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top',
        });
        toast.present();
      }
    } else {
      if (this.players[index].playerType == playerType) {
        if (
          this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].countSelection >=
          this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].maxSelection
        ) {
          this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
          const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message:
              'Select maximun ' +
              this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].maxSelection +
              '  ' +
              this.players[index].playerType,
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'top',
          });
          toast.present();
        } else {
          if (this.totalPlayer >= 11) {
            this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
            const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'u can select only 11 players',
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'top',
            });
            toast.present();
          } else {
            if (this.team1player >= 7 && this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team1Name) {
              this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
              const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: 'u can select only 7 player from ' + this.matchData.data.team1Name,
                duration: 3000,
                position: 'top',
              });
              toast.present();
            } else if (this.team2player >= 7 && this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team2Name) {
              this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
              const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: 'u can select only 7 player from ' + this.matchData.data.team2Name,
                duration: 3000,
                position: 'top',
              });
              toast.present();
            } else {
              this.players[index].isSelected = true;
              this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].countSelection =
                this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].countSelection + 1;
              this.totalCreaditPoint -= parseFloat(this.players[index].playerCreditPoint);
              if (this.selectedPlayers.indexOf(this.players[index]) == -1) {
                console.log(this.players[index].teamName);
                console.log(this.matchData.data.team1Name);
                console.log(this.matchData.data.team1Name);
                if (this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team1Name) {
                  this.team1player++;
                } else if (this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team2Name) {
                  this.team2player++;
                }
                this.selectedPlayers.push(this.players[index].playerUid);
                this.storage.set('team', this.selectedPlayers);
                this.storage.get('team').then(val => {
                  console.log(val);
                });
                this.totalPlayer++;
              }
              console.log('team1player:' + this.team1player);
              console.log('team2player:' + this.team2player);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```